# is there a way to uncompress zip data without ByteArray.inflate()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, zip

Is there a way to uncompress ziped data without inflate()?

thank you in advance!

Comment: i'm curious why you are drawn to finding an alternative?  is `ByteArray.inflate()` very slow?

Comment: If what you want is a solution that doesn't require Flash Player 10, maybe this can work http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/ I'm not sure it will, but at least it has been around since before Flash Player 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the hard way.

You can use [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) for that. Alchemy is a free tool for porting C/C++ code into flash. In Alchemy sdk examples there already are ported versions of [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/) and [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). So you can use gzip to uncompress your zipped data.